# need help installing a python package which uses Cython and Boost c++ on Windows 10

Tags: python, c++, windows, boost, cython

I've been trying to install this **[python package](https://github.com/berlinade/python-transient-gas-network-simulator)** on **windows**, but unsuccessfully so far.

it uses **Cython** and **cyCada** to interface with C++ and use the **boost** library.

I have VS2022 community installed and i added the boost library to its include directory.

using **MSVC**, when i run `python setup.py install` this is what i get.

```
Compiling src_cython/cycADa_interface.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing src_cython/cycADa_interface.pyx
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'cycADa_interface' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpbuild\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.obj -std=c++11
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-std=c++11' inconnue ignorée
cycADa_interface.cpp
C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(7250): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(7259): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(7268): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(8201): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(8210): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(8459): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(8676): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(8873): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp(9090): warning C4267: '=' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'int', perte possible de données
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc_cpp/cycADa_adouble.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_adouble.obj -std=c++11
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-std=c++11' inconnue ignorée
cycADa_adouble.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_tape.obj -std=c++11
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-std=c++11' inconnue ignorée
cycADa_tape.cpp
src_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp(29): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion de 'double' en 'const _Ty', perte possible de données
        with
        [
            _Ty=long
        ]
src_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp(78): warning C4267: 'return' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données
src_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp(82): warning C4267: 'return' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données
src_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp(86): warning C4267: 'return' : conversion de 'size_t' en 'long', perte possible de données
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc_cpp/cycADa_elemOp.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_elemOp.obj -std=c++11
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-std=c++11' inconnue ignorée
cycADa_elemOp.cpp
creating C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ad\cycADa\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Python38\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Python38\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_cycADa_interface build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_adouble.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_tape.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp/cycADa_elemOp.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.lib
   Création de la bibliothèque build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.lib et de l'objet build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Génération de code en cours
Fin de la génération du code
running install_lib
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.pyd -> C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.8.egg-info
Writing C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.8.egg-info
```

When i try to run the example provided in the package i get this:

```
[INFO]: start implicit Euler integration from t0 = 0.0 to T = 111600.0, with H = 180.0

Elapsed (time): 00-00-00.154
Elapsed (proc): 00-00-00.125

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rabhi.yacine/Desktop/cyc/python-transient-gas-network-simulator/example/GasLib40_modified/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    simulate_gas_network(configPath)
  File "C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\simulator\configurator.py", line 70, in simulate_gas_network
    imp_euler_report = integrate(net,
  File "C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\paso\solvers\dae\ImpEuler.py", line 167, in integrate 
    out = ImpEulerStep(sys_func = sys_func,
  File "C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\paso\solvers\dae\ImpEuler.py", line 43, in ImpEulerStep
    if use_cycADa: _inner_step_func, _inner_step_Dfunc = cycADa_wrapper(inner_step_func, dim_x)
  File "C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\paso\differentiation\util\wrapper_cycADa.py", line 18, in cycADa_wrapper
    trace.allocJac(False)                                  # allocate cycADa memory for Jacobian
  File "src_cython\cycADa_interface.pyx", line 512, in cycADa_interface.tape.allocJac
  File "src_cython\cycADa_interface.pyx", line 478, in cycADa_interface.tape.set_grad_pointer
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int_t' but got 'long long'
```

I also tried to use **MinGw** to install this package.
So i installed MinGw provided in this [link](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)
and then i had to create a distutils.cfg file in the python Lib/disutils folder

**distutils.cfg**

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

when i run `python setup.py install` this is what i get.

```
Compiling src_cython/cycADa_interface.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing src_cython/cycADa_interface.pyx
running install
running build
running build_ext
dllwrap: WARNING: dllwrap is deprecated, use gcc -shared or ld -shared instead

building 'cycADa_interface' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" -c build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycada_interface.o -std=c++11
In file included from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:4,
                 from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp:748:
C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:168:20: warning: 'int _fseeki64(FILE*, long long int, int)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
  168 | extern int __cdecl _fseeki64(FILE *, long long, int);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:169:26: warning: 'long long int _ftelli64(FILE*)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
  169 | extern long long __cdecl _ftelli64(FILE *);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822,
                 from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp:748:
C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:77: note: '#pragma message: C:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION'
   15 |                          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")
      |                                                                             ^
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp: In function 'PyTypeObject* __Pyx_ImportType(PyObject*, const char*, const char*, size_t, __Pyx_ImportType_CheckSize)':
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp:39358:24: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
39358 |             "Expected %zd from C header, got %zd from PyObject",
      |                        ^
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp:39358:47: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
39358 |             "Expected %zd from C header, got %zd from PyObject",
      |                                               ^
build\src_cython/cycADa_interface.cpp:39357:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
39357 |             "%s.%s size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. "
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
39358 |             "Expected %zd from C header, got %zd from PyObject",
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" -c src_cpp/cycADa_adouble.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_adouble.o -std=c++11
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" -c src_cpp/cycADa_tape.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_tape.o -std=c++11
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc_cython -IC:\Users\rabhi.yacine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python38\include" -c src_cpp/cycADa_elemOp.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_elemop.o -std=c++11
writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.def
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycada_interface.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_adouble.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_tape.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src_cpp\cycada_elemop.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src_cython\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.def "-LC:\Program Files\Python38\libs" "-LC:\Program Files\Python38\PCbuild\amd64" -lpython38 -lmsvcr143 -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cycADa_interface.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcr143
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help on how i could install on windows would be amazing.
I have tried on linux and it works great. but i have to create an executable for distribution on windows so i have to install it on windows to then use pyinstaller to create an exe (pyinstaller does not support cross compiling)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep using MSVC. MinGW isn't really supported as a Windows compiler (it probably can be made to work but it's easier not to have to)

You may want to edit setup.py to change `-std=c++11` to `/std:c++14` (just so MSVC understands the option... I've used c++14 since MSVC doesn't seem to have a c++11 flag).

Your issue is then that the code is written with some poor platform compatibility assumptions. Your current error is from:

```
np.ndarray[np.int_t, mode="c", ndim=1] local_indices
np.ndarray[np.int_t, mode="c", ndim=1] local_indptr
...
local_indices = np.zeros(shape = (len_z + len_y, ), dtype = np.int64)
local_indptr  = np.zeros(shape = (s + m + 1, ), dtype = np.int64)
```

It makes the assumption that an `int` is 64 bits, which is not true on Windows.

Change the first two lines from `np.int_t` to `np.int64_t`.

You may find you need to fix a whole bunch of similar errors. The authors seem to have been clear that they haven't tested on anything but linux.

Comment: Man I cannot thank you enough, you just saved me a whole lot of headaches! i made the changes you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much. I wish i could upvote but i dont have enough rep.